# How to remove branches that don't contain a certain value in a php array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I've spent the day playing with deceze's answer but I'm no closer to making it work.  I may have part of it, but not sure how to get recursion in array_filter.

My Array looks like this (sample):

```
Array
(
    [name] => root
    [ChildCats] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Air Conditioning
                    [ChildCats] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Ducted Air Conditioning
                                    [ChildCats] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Supply & Install
                                                    [ChildCats] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [name] => Daiken
                                                                    [S] => 6067
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Supply Only
                                                    [ChildCats] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [name] => Mitsubishi
                                                                    [S] => 6026
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Split System Air Conditioning
                                    [ChildCats] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Supply & Install
                                                    [ChildCats] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [name] => Daiken
                                                                    [S] => 6067
                                                                )

                                                            [1] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [name] => Fujitsu Split Air Conditioning Systems
                                                                    [S] => 6464
                                                                )

                                                            [2] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [name] => Mitsubishi Electric Split Air Conditioning Systems
                                                                    [S] => 6464
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Appliance / White Goods
                    [ChildCats] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Clearance
                                    [S] => 6239
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Cooktops
                                    [ChildCats] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Ceramic Cooktops
                                                    [S] => 6239
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Element Cooktops
                                                    [S] => 6067
                                                )

                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Gas Cooktops
                                                    [S] => 6239
                                                )

                                            [3] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Induction Cooktops
                                                    [S] => 6239
                                                )

                                        )

                                )


                        )

                )
```

Now lets say I try to extract just the parts of the array relevent to the following keypair:

S => 6067.

I'd like the result to look like:

```
Array
(
    [name] => root
    [ChildCats] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Air Conditioning
                    [ChildCats] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Ducted Air Conditioning
                                    [ChildCats] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Supply & Install
                                                    [ChildCats] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [name] => Daiken
                                                                    [S] => 6067
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Split System Air Conditioning
                                    [ChildCats] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Supply & Install
                                                    [ChildCats] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [name] => Daiken
                                                                    [S] => 6067
                                                                )


                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Appliance / White Goods
                    [ChildCats] => Array
                        (

                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Cooktops
                                    [ChildCats] => Array
                                        (

                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Element Cooktops
                                                    [S] => 6067
                                                )


                                        )

                                )


                        )

                )
    )
)
```

What I cannot get my head arround is should I be creating a new array or using array filter.

Playing with deceze code I've got the search working using the following:

```
function recursive_assoc_in_array(array $haystack,  array $needle, $childKey = 'ChildCats') {

    if (array_intersect_assoc($haystack, $needle)) {
        echo "Found via array_intersect_assoc ".$haystack[name]."\n";
        return true;    
    } 

    foreach ($haystack[$childKey] as $child) {

         if (recursive_assoc_in_array($child, $needle, $childKey)) return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

But if I try to process with,

```
$array = array_filter($array, function (array $values) {
    return recursive_assoc_in_array($values, array('S' => '6067'));
});
```

I get the original array which leads me to think I have to get recursion running on the array_filter query.

At this point I just go blank.

Additionally, the array keys will need to be reindexed on the produced new array. Any ideas?

--Additional 7/7/14

How about if I try to build a new array from the old one?

I'm trying:

```
function exploreArrayandAdd($Array) {

    if ($Array['ChildCats']) {

        foreach ($Array['ChildCats'] as $key => $value) {
            $NewArray['ChildCats'][] = exploreArrayandAdd($value);
        }

    } else {

        if ($Array['S'] == 6026) {
            //echo "1";
            return $Array;
        } 

    }

}
```

But cannot work out how to pass the new array out of the function?

Tried removing branches that don't match using:

```
function exploreArray(&$Array) {

    if ($Array['ChildCats']) {

        foreach ($Array['ChildCats'] as $key => $value) {
            $result = exploreArray($Array['ChildCats'][$key]);

            if ($result === false)
                unset($Array['ChildCats'][$key]);

        }

    } else {
        //  print_r($Array);
        if ($Array['S'] == 6026) {
            return true;
        } else {
            unset($Array);
            return false;
        }

    }
    //if ($NoChildCat==true) print_r($Array);

}
```

But I believe it is the wrong way as it does work at the bottom of the array but not back up towards the top as siblings make result true.
Also this won't reindex the array keys.

Comment: Show the code you've attempted to solve this issue.

Comment: So you know how to recursively traverse the tree to find the value? Then just make a function out of that: `treeContainsValue(array $tree, $value)`, and then code which loops through the top level and does `if (!treeContainsValue(...)) unset(...)`.

Comment: You just supplied the array....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function recursive_array_filter(array $array, $childKey, callable $test) {
    if (isset($array[$childKey]) && is_array($array[$childKey])) {
        foreach ($array[$childKey] as $key => &$child) {
            if (!$child = recursive_array_filter($child, $childKey, $test)) {
                unset($array[$childKey][$key]);
            }
        }
        if (!$array[$childKey]) {
            unset($array[$childKey]);
        }
    }
    return !empty($array[$childKey]) || $test($array) ? $array : [];
}

$array = recursive_array_filter($array, 'ChildCats', function (array $array) {
    return array_intersect_assoc($array, ['S' => 6026]);
});
```

To express the algorithm in words: you descend down into the array first, following all `ChildCats` branches to their end. In each level you return the values as they are back to the caller if they match your test *or* if they have children, or you return an emptied array (you could also return `false` if you prefer). If some child turns out empty, you prune it with `unset`.

I have implemented the test as a callback function here for best reusability of the code.

Comment: I'd love to say I understand your code deceze but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: I don't think this'll actually work for you, I misunderstood the goal before you clarified your question. This will remove any branches from **the top** of the array only which do not contain the desired value. It does not selectively prune branches lower in the hierarchy. I'll have another look at this when I have a little more time.

Comment: I've added a test area http://codepad.org/dkWhrBCC.
I'll add some more notes to the main query too.

Comment: Thanks deceze - I'm currently close but still getting empty branches.

http://codepad.org/rJw6iei6

Comment: @user Updated with the solution.

Comment: function recursive_array_filter(array $array, $childKey, callable $test) {
 if (isset($array[$childKey]) && is_array($array[$childKey])) {
  echo "1";
  foreach ($array[$childKey] as $key => &$child) {
   if (!$child = recursive_array_filter($child, $childKey, $test)) {
    unset($array[$childKey][$key]);
   }
  }
  if (!$array[$childKey]) {
   unset($array[$childKey]);
  }
 }
 return !empty($array[$childKey]) || $test($array) ? $array : FALSE;
}

Comment: I've swapped [] with false and ['S'=>6026] with array('S'=>6026) which I believe is needed to make it work?  
I'm getting a php error:
 Argument 3 passed to recursive_array_filter() must be an instance of callable, instance of Closure given.
I do appreciate this and am learning heaps.  IE the shorthand logic in the return is now making sense.
Is it if not empty childkey array or search value in array return the array else return false.  I've never seen callable before which is a complete trip.  But what the heck is an instance of Closure?
Thanks Again.

Comment: Removed callable from the funtion input variables.  Works perfectly now.  Will now pull it a part line by line to understand it in more details.  Thanks deceze.

Comment: Ah, yes, `callable` and `[]` are syntax additions in PHP 5.4. Seems you're on 5.3. Your fixes are correct.